# A non-abelian group of order $p^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to show that for a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ for $p$ prime there exist a short exact sequence 
$$
1\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p}\overset{j}{\rightarrow}G \overset{p}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times \mathbb{Z}_{p}\rightarrow 1
$$

I have proved that the center of $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, which contains also the commutator of $G$. The center is a subgroup of $G$, so the first map $j$ is obviously an inclusion. Now I am stuck in the proof of the surjectivity of $p$ and that $\operatorname{Im}(j)=\operatorname{Ker}(p)$. Can anybody help me with this question? I would appreciate any comments and hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's known that $G/Z(G)$ cannot be cyclic and that $Z(G)$ is not trivial in a finite $p$-group. Thus $|Z(G)|=p$ and $|G/Z(G)|=p^2$. Thus $G/Z(G)$ is abelian and not cyclic, hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, we can identify $\mathbb Z_p$ with the center $C(G)$. Now prove that we can identify $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p$ with $G/C(G)$, and let $p$ be the projection map (which is surjective). Then we get exactness right away.